# attach domain name with lightsail instense and django

Tags: django, amazon-lightsail

I have created static ip in lightsail and attached it to the django instanse. I bought domain name from godaddy. I then created domain zone in lightsail and created 2 DNS records type "A" with the following:
@.drmahahabib.com
[www.drmahahabib.com](http://www.drmahahabib.com)

Then i copied the name servers from the same page for my lightsail then took that to godaddy site and changed the name servers there.

Now i get the page that confirms that the lightsail is working but not the site instense of django. do i need to do some modification?

below is the screenshot or just visit the webpage.
[my site](http://www.drmahahabib.com)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Django internal dev server use

[www.drmahahabib.com:8000](http://www.drmahahabib.com:8000)

Here 8000 is the port on which you ran the Django server. If you are using another port replace 8000 with your port number

If you want to make your site live on [www.drmahahabib.com](http://www.drmahahabib.com) then you have to configure Apache to serve your application.